# Unable to resolving the promise inside of a function

Tags: javascript

Here is a piece of my original code, Why I can't resolve the instruct function this way?

Actually I used to resolve the promises like this and the same codes for other functions worked before.

I'm not able to find the reason and the solution without a hand.

```js
var instructResolve;
async function instruct(location, category){

    switch(location) {

          case 'User_Was_Silent':
          console.log('Start!')
          await audioPlay();
          console.log('After audioPlay await is done, then resolve instruct!')
          instructResolve();
          
          break;
    }
    
    return new Promise((resolve) => { 
    instructResolve = resolve;
    });


};


function audioPlay(source){

  console.log('await audioPlay..') 
  
 return new Promise((resolve) => {
  setTimeout(function(){
     console.log('audioPlay resolved..')
     resolve(); 
  }, 5000)
                
  }); 
} 


recognize();
async function recognize(){

await instruct('User_Was_Silent');
//After resolving instruct do stuff like logging some success message on the console
console.log('Final log success!')

}
```

At the `recognize` function I'm waiting for the `instruct` function to resolve and then we do stuff like logging some success message on the console, but since `recognize`  for some reason doesn't resolve we can not see the `console.log('Final log success!')`

**UPDATE:**
I have a similar code that works just fine without any issues, I have implemented the promises and resolves just like the code above but it works!

```js
var updateGuiderResolve;
function updateGuider(state, guide, lower){
console.log('updateGuider...')
    switch(state) {

          case 'default':
          stateReveal("default");
          break;     
         
    }

          return new Promise((resolve) => { 
          updateGuiderResolve = resolve;
          });

}

function stateReveal(state){
   console.log('stateReveal...')
   setTimeout(function(){
   speak();
   }, 5000);

}

function speak(){
console.log('speak...')
setTimeout(function(){
console.log('updateGuiderResolve...')
   updateGuiderResolve()
   }, 5000);

}

async function tutor(){
await updateGuider('default');
console.log('final...')

}
tutor()
```

Comment: You are calling `instructResolve()` before you have defined it as `instructResolve = resolve`

Comment: Can you see other console logs of other functions ? By checking console logs you can check where your code breaks

Comment: @ Nipun Jain yes...

Comment: @ ButchMonkey  WHAT?

Comment: @SaraRee you are calling `instructResolve` function before defining it as `instructResolve = resolve`. May be thats the issue

Comment: Any idea how to fix that?

Comment: Try calling `recognize` function after initializing it. I think that not the issue but just to confirm

Comment: Sorry... I'm so much confused... Can you please provide an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can see 2 problems in the code base.

One is

```
instructResolve(); // It's not function, I think as it's only declared at first.
```

Second one is

```
await instruct('User_Was_Silent'); // This does not need to add await as it's already async function. Simply call instruct('User_Was_Silent'); and missing second param in this function.
```

```js
    var instructResolve;
    async function instruct(location, category=null){
    
        switch(location) {
    
              case 'User_Was_Silent':
              console.log('Start!')
              await audioPlay();
              console.log('After audioPlay await is done, then resolve instruct!')
              
              
              break;
        }    
    };
    
    
    function audioPlay(source){
     console.log('await audioPlay..') 
    
     return new Promise((resolve) => {
      setTimeout(function(){
         console.log('audioPlay resolved..')
         resolve(); 
      }, 5000)
                    
      }); 
    } 
    
async function recognize(){

   await instruct('User_Was_Silent');
   //After resolving instruct do stuff like logging some success message on the console
   console.log('Final log success!')

}
recognize();
```

Comment: Without `await instruct` the `console.log('Final log success!')` executes at once and that's not the thing I want..

Comment: @SaraRee Please check edited answer. I can see all logs

Comment: That's working plus one but please look at my Update.

Comment: Yes. The problem is that. Async function is return promise and promise function can return value through resolve and reject function.
await function is for calling promise function inside async function.

Comment: @SaraRee Answer was updated. Please check.
Actually, you don't need to call new promise function inside instruct function because it will be ended automatically.
And simply call instruct function directly.

Comment: I want to run this line `console.log('Final log success!')` only if `instruct` function ends.

Comment: Okay. Please try to check answer now.

Comment: How it worked you didn't resolve the instruct but the code waits for it ...!!!

Answer (score 0):

Try calling instructResolve inside Promise like that:

```
var instructResolve;
async function instruct(location, category){
 switch(location) {
   case 'User_Was_Silent':
   console.log('Start!')
   await audioPlay();
   console.log('After audioPlay await is done, then resolve instruct!')
   break;
 }

 return new Promise((resolve) => { 
    instructResolve = resolve;
    instructResolve();
 });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a solution like this one but I want to know why the question's code doesn't work?

```js
var instructResolve;
async function instruct(location, category){
    return new Promise(async (resolve) => { 
    switch(location) {

          case 'User_Was_Silent':
          console.log('Start!')
          await audioPlay();
          console.log('After audioPlay await is done, then resolve instruct!')
          resolve();
          
          break;
    }
    
    
   
    });


};


function audioPlay(source){

  console.log('await audioPlay..') 
  
 return new Promise((resolve) => {
  setTimeout(function(){
     console.log('audioPlay resolved..')
     resolve(); 
  }, 5000)
                
  }); 
} 



async function recognize(){

await instruct('User_Was_Silent');
//After resolving instruct do stuff like logging some success message on the console
console.log('Final log success!')

}

recognize();
```